# Correct way to find Users/<name> directory in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, windows-services

I have tried a lot of solutions but I am unable to get the desired result. I am privy to the fact that one can use Environment.SpecialFolder enumeration. I have already tried them all but in vain. I am writing a service that needs to access this folder in C#>
C:\Users\Shahbaaz\efb

Working on Win 7, .Net 4, VS13

UPDATE:
MY problem is that I can't programmatically access C:\Users\Shahbaaz.Shahbaaz is the name of the logged in account. The efb folder was used for illustration only. Sorry about that. I had used UserProfile enum but ended up with C:\SYSTEM directory. CommonDocuments et al give me the C:\Users\Public... directories. Also, if I just use Environment.Username, it gives me SYSTEM instead of the logged in username. Hope this helps!

Comment: What's exactly going wrong? What did you get using the SpecialFolder enumeration? And what's the "efb" folder? That is something non-standard.

Comment: MY problem is that I can't programmatically access C:\Users\Shahbaaz.Shahbaaz is the name of the logged in account. The efb folder was used for illustration only. Sorry about that. I had used UserProfile enum but ended up with C:\SYSTEM directory. CommonDocuments et al give me the C:\Users\Public\... directories. Also, if I just use Environment.Username, it gives me SYSTEM instead of the logged in username. Hope this helps!

Comment: Did you read the docs on Environment.SpecialFolder? It looks like you should use SpecialFolder.UserProfile.

Comment: I did. UserProfile led me to this directory: C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what's going on. Wrote a small test:

```
[Test]
public void PrintAllSpecialFolders()
{
    var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Environment.SpecialFolder));
    Console.WriteLine("Printing special folder paths:");
    foreach (Environment.SpecialFolder value in values)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", value, Environment.GetFolderPath(value, Environment.SpecialFolderOption.None));
    }
 }
```

That clearly shows the expected result (Windows 7):

```
 ...
 UserProfile: C:\Users\<myusername>
 ...
```

**But**: You're using a service (which your tag indicates) and you're probably running the service under the LocalSystem account. The local system account doesn't have an user folder in the expected place. Either run your service under your user account or accept the given path as profile folder for the LocalSystem account. Do not try to access your user account from LocalSystem. You'll probably get a permission error.

Comment: Thanks! This is an eye opener. Turns out, to run my service on (my) user account I need to mention my password every time it installs. Now this can be a hindrance, as I am writing a dynamic service, executable  on any pc as part of my project. Maybe, I shall change the required folders' location to mitigate this once and for all. Thanks again!